# Can multiple xbees send data to one xbee

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee

I am new to xbees. I want to have multiple xbees (up to 400 xbees) send data constantly to one xbee (receiver).This is just simple data like lets say 0 or 1 . Is this possible? Are there any limitations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can send data from 400 XBees to a single xbee. I would like to clarify one thing. XBees are connecting to a network, not to a particular xbee. And the devices connected in a network can communicate each other.

Comment: Thank you. My goal afterwards is for the receiver xbee connected to wifi module to send the data from all 400 xbees to the server.I am assuming that is also possible?